# Datagrid Minimum Date in DateTime Field

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a datepicker in a cell of my datagrid and I would like to set the date to some default date so that when I create a new row in my datagrid it doesnt create a datetime2 date of "1/1/0001". Here is my datagrid template.

```
   <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Date Filled">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DateFilled,Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=DateFilled,Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

How would I go about doing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to assign the default value in the view model.  For example:

```
public DateTime DateFilled
{
    get { return _dateFilled; }
    set 
    { 
        _dateFilled = value;  
        RaisePropertyChanged("DateFilled");
    }
}
private DateTime _dateFilled = DateTime.Today;
```

---

Alternatively, you could make the view-model property a nullable `DateTime?`.  That way, you can use the binding's [`TargetNullValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.targetnullvalue.aspx):  `SelectedDate="{Binding Path=DateFilled,Mode=TwoWay,TargetNullValue={x:Static DateTime.Now}}"`

Comment: I get this Error when trying to apply the {x:Static }: DateTime is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) projectt. you need to add sys: namespace in the begging... Plus - it doesn't work on my not null field.....